# Image erosion and dilation with Scipy

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scipy

I am trying to use scipy to do [erosion](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_erosion.html) and [dilation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html) of an image. It seems pretty straightforward using scipy -> `binary_erosion / dialation`. However, the output is not at all what is expected.

Here is my basic code:

```
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import Image

#im = Image.open('flower.png')
im = ndimage.imread('flower.png')
im = ndimage.binary_erosion(im).astype(np.float32)
scipy.misc.imsave('erosion.png', im)


im2 = Image.open('flower.png')
im2 = ndimage.binary_dilation(im2)
scipy.misc.imsave('dilation.png', im2)
```

This is the output:

[image]

The output for dilation is just a completely white image for the original "flower.png"

I believe that I must specify a better kernel or mask but am not really sure why I am getting a green output for erosion and completely white output for dilation.

Comment: binary operators expect binary input unlike yours

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was using the binary erosion instead of the [grey erosion](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.grey_erosion.html#scipy.ndimage.morphology.grey_erosion) array. I converted the original image to greyscale by using `flatten=true` like so:

```
im = scipy.misc.imread('flower.png', flatten=True).astype(np.uint8)
```

then called:

```
im1 = ndimage.grey_erosion(im, size=(15,15))
```

And got a nicely eroded picture, although it is greyscale.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems: as noted in the comment by @theta, binary ops expect input consisting only of 0 and 1. The second issue is the `nd` in `ndimage` --- you supply in an array of shape `(nx, ny, 3)`. The last length-3 axis is considered to be a third spatial dimension, not the three color channels.