# Alternative to .dilate() OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am using `cv2` and `Pillow` in my script:

```
image = Image.open("img1.png")
#do some stuff to the image
image.save("result1.png")

image = cv2.imread("result1.png")
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
dilated_image = cv2.dilate(image, kernel, iterations=3)
cv2.imwrite("result2.png", dilated_image)

final_image = Image.open("result2.png")
#do some other stuff to the image
final_image.save("final_result.png")
```

As you can see, I have to switch between `OpenCV` and `Pillow`, and save three images. What I want, is to save just **one** result, instead of **three**.

Is there a way, where I can continue with Pillow, dilate the image with almost the **same execution speed**, without using cv2?

I have already tried `image.filter(ImageFilter.MaxFilter(size=3))`, but it takes too much CPU time. The reason it takes too much time, is that for having the same effect as `cv2.dilate(image, kernel, iterations=5)`, I should  use at least `image.filter(ImageFilter.MaxFilter(size=15))`

Comment: How about this function [`PIL.ImageFilter.MaxFilter`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/ImageFilter.html#PIL.ImageFilter.MaxFilter)?

Comment: @ikkuh I have tried that and it's much slower, since the iterations should be larger compared to cv2

Comment: Why not implement the morphological operation manually?

Comment: @JohnSmith Seems to me that the [`ImageMorph`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/ImageMorph.html) module is the closest -- check out the [tests](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/Tests/test_imagemorph.py). Unfortunately it only seems to support 3x3 kernels. | "without being slower in CPU time" -- Doubt it. The OpenCV implementation is vectorized by hand, and from cursory look, there's nothing close to that level of optimization in the Pillow codebase. And anything you'd write in pure Python has no hope of matching the speed.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds How would I go about manually implementation?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I edited the question, maybe it's more clear now

Comment: As @DanMašek said, with a manual implementation you have no chance of matching the speed. SciPy is your best alternative if you want to avoid OpenCV. Otherwise you'll need to give up one of your requirements. The easiest way to replicate the `iterations` on OpenCV is to just manually iterate the Pillow function `iterations` times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for an OpenCV alternative for the function which is there in a standard library, then you can try SciPy's function (SO Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853875/image-erosion-and-dilation-with-scipy))

Comment: I am looking for a Pillow alternative, since I want to replace my whole script with Pillow